# error in installation of tidyverse package in R

Tags: r, linux, tidyverse, r-package, ubuntu-22.04

I am facing an error during the installation of tidyverse R package. The R version is 4.2.0 and OS is ubuntu 22.04 (in windows host OS). I have used the following command in R for the installation:

```
install.package("tidyverse",dependencies=TRUE)
```

After the installation when I called the library using library(tidyverse), it gives an error:

> System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't
> operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down

along a warning message: `

> Warning message:In system("timedatectl", intern = TRUE) :  running
> command 'timedatectl' had status 1

`

Kindly help troubleshoot the error.

Comment: [`"ubuntu" System has not been booted with systemd as init system`](https://www.google.com/search?q="ubuntu"+System+has+not+been+booted+with+systemd+as+init+system) suggests https://askubuntu.com/q/1379425/399638

Comment: This answer is too technical to understand. Can you provide a simple explanation?

Comment: Based on the first couple of paragraphs only of that answer, and another google search of [`"tidyverse" "systemd"`](https://www.google.com/search?q="tidyverse"+"systemd") (quotes are very useful in google searches!), there's https://skeptric.com/tidyverse-timedatectl-wsl2/ (and less-so https://community.rstudio.com/t/timedatectl-had-status-1/72060/2), which seems to have some more salient information.

Comment: It seems nothing is working out. I tried the tutorial you have suggested and some others which I found. But nothing is helping the troubleshoot. Any other suggestions are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: I vaguely recall encountering something similar before myself.  After the error, are you able to use normally?

Comment: No, after using the package with different bash scripts it gives the same error: "System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down". after that command is terminated. If you can recall the solution, it will be a great help.